# Refractive indices of liquid crystal

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses, crystals, birefringence

Refractive indices of liquid crystal • The birefringence is critical to the optical properties of the liquid crystal and underlies many of the applications of liquid crystals. • By reorienting the liquid crystal the effective birefringence will change and so the optical properties will change. How is reorienting the liquid crystal the effective birefringence will change?

Comment: Do you know what [birefringence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) means?

Comment: @DanDan0101, yes. I am not sure how is this related to liquid crystal ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to think of "effective birefringence" as "the optical properties along one specific axis" here. When the liquid crystal is reoriented (i.e. when we pick a different axis), the optical properties will change.